# Adjusting the Height of a Kendo Multi-Select

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am trying to adjust the default height (& line height) of a Kendo Multi-Select to fit-in with the sizing of other controls on the screen.  I "started" trying to use the same CSS you would use for a Kendo DropDownList...but that seems to fail.

**CSS:**

```
.k-multiselect { display: inline-block; width: 400px;}
.k-multiselect-wrap .k-input { line-height: 20px; }
.k-multiselect-wrap .k-select { line-height: 1.7em; min-height: 1em; }
```

**CODE:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
      .Name("msPurpose")
      .AutoClose(false)
      .TagMode(TagMode.Single)
      .DataTextField("PurposeCategory")
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .BindTo(Model.Purposes)
      .Value(Model.Purposes)
      .ItemTemplate("<input type='checkbox' name='chkPurpose' value='#:data.Id#' checked /> #:data.PurposeCategory#"))
```

**RESULT:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with css:

```
.k-multiselect-wrap {
  height: 25px;
}

.k-multiselect-wrap li {
   font-size: 8px;
}

.k-multiselect-wrap .k-input {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.k-list .k-item {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

Example: [MultiSelect style](https://dojo.telerik.com/aMidEvoS)